# How will I send mail in Android?

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I tried to send mail using with intent but it didn't work.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{adres});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, konu);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, icerik);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "it didn't work" means.

Comment: nothing happens there is no new message on my mail box.

Comment: There is not supposed to be a "new message on [your] mail box". `startActivity()` starts an activity. So, what activity gets started?

Comment: I didn't understand what you are asking the code is on the top. I just want to send mail in android. How will I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
              email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});  
              email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);  
              email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);  

              //need this to prompts email client only  
              email.setType("message/rfc822");  

              startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below line:

`startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email with: "));`